# Haversine formula, PHP, to add in 2nd table if conditions apply

Tags: php, android, haversine

I am trying to implement `Haversine Formula` to check the latitudes/longitudes of a table. My android app stores all the incoming locations in a database, in a particular table , `inregistrari`. My goal is to get the formula to test the new incoming locations based on longitude and latitude, and if the distance between the new values and the ones existing in `alerte`(2nd table) is more than 50m, to `insert` the locations into both tables(`alerte` , `inregistrari`), else, only in `inregistrari`. The new values has to be verified with all the locations stored in `alerte`. So, at the end i would get a table with all the locations(`inregistrari`), and the 2nd one only with the locations that do not have any other location within 50m(`alerte`). I have tried to implement `( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) )` but could not manage to make it work the way I want. I seek for guidance because of the `PHP` , I am not actually very familiar with this yet. As 1st step, I managed to create the `PHP` to automatically `insert` directly in both tables, now I only need to implement `Haversine`. Thanks in advance!

php try to implement haversine:

```
case 'alerta':

            if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('latitudine', 'longitudine', 'id_alerta_tip', 'ID_user'))){

                $problema = $_POST['id_alerta_tip'];
                $latitudine = $_POST['latitudine'];
                $longitudine = $_POST['longitudine'];
                $id = $_POST['ID_user'];

                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT latitudine, longitudine FROM inregistrari WHERE latitudine = ? AND longitudine = ?");
                $stmt->bind_param("ss", $latitudine, $longitudine);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->store_result();

                if($stmt->num_rows < 1){
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO inregistrari (ID_user, id_alerta_tip, latitudine, longitudine) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
                $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $id, $problema, $latitudine, $longitudine);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->store_result();
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM alerte WHERE id_alerta_tip = ?");
                $stmt->bind_param("s",$problema);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->store_result();
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt))
                {
                    $latitudine1=$row[latitudine];
                    $longitudine1=$row[longitudine];
                    function getDistance($latitude1, $longitude1, $latitude2, $longitude2) {  
                    $earth_radius = 6371;  
                    $dLat = deg2rad($latitude2 - $latitude1);  
                    $dLon = deg2rad($longitude2 - $longitude1);  
                    $a = sin($dLat/2) * sin($dLat/2) + cos(deg2rad($latitude1)) * cos(deg2rad($latitude2)) * sin($dLon/2) * sin($dLon/2);  
                    $c = 2 * asin(sqrt($a));  
                    $d = $earth_radius * $c;  
                    return $d;  
                    }  
                    if(getDistance($latitudine,$longitudine,$latitudine1,$longitudine1)<0.05)
                    {
                        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO alerte(id_utilizator, latitudine, longitudine, tip_problema) VALUES ('$id','$latitudine', '$longitudine', '$problema')");
                        $stmt->execute();
                    }

                }

                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id_alerta FROM alerte WHERE latitudine = ? AND longitudine = ?");
                $stmt->bind_param("ss", $latitudine, $longitudine);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->store_result();
                if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
                $stmt->bind_result($id_alerta);
                $stmt->fetch();
                $stmt= $conn->prepare("UPDATE inregistrari SET ID_Alerta_Primarie = ? WHERE latitudine = ? AND longitudine = ?");
                $stmt->bind_param("iss",$id_alerta ,$latitudine, $longitudine);
                $stmt->execute();   
                $stmt->close();
                }else{
                    $response['error'] = false; 
                    $response['message'] = 'Alerta nu a putut fi inregistrata';
                }
                    $response['error'] = false; 
                    $response['message'] = 'Alerta raportata';                      
                }else{
                    $response['error'] = false; 
                    $response['message'] = 'Alerta nu a putut fi inregistrata';
                }
            }else{
                    $response['error'] = false; 
                    $response['message'] = 'Alerta nu a putut fi inregistrata';
                }
            break;
```

I have tried to implement a `while` to get every row at once, but it is not working. The code stops running before the `while` statement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the actual Haversine formula:

```
R = earth’s radius (mean radius = 6,371km)
Δlat = lat2− lat1
Δlong = long2− long1
a = sin²(Δlat/2) + cos(lat1).cos(lat2).sin²(Δlong/2)
c = 2.atan2(√a, √(1−a))
d = R.c
Angles need to be in radians to pass to Trigonometric functions
```

And here is the MySQL equivalent:

```
SELECT *, 
 ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(55.864237) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
 * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-4.251806) ) + sin( radians(55.864237) ) 
 * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM postcodes HAVING distance < 20 
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 1;
```

Here I check for any area within 20 miles, but you can make this as short or long as you want.  The 3959 figure at the start of the query is the number used for miles, if you are using kilometres you should change this number to 6371.  I have limited it to 1 row, as I only want the closest match, however you may want to change this in other situations!

Here's the Wiki for Haversine http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Good luck!